# C# Parse command line string with spaces. System.IO.Path and FileInfo fails

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for a reliable way to parse a path string that has spaces

e.g

```
"C:/Test has spaces/More Spaces.exe argument"
```

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` works (returns `"C:/Test has spaces"`), but `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` returns `"More Spaces.exe argument"`. I want get the .exe and split the arguments .

The string is not double quoted so let's say I cannot modify the input string.

Comment: Are you looking for `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` or `GetExtension()`? Not really sure what it is you are asking here. See [`System.IO.Path` methods list.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods)

Comment: something like that could work: find the last ".exe" in the string, everything after is part of the argument(s).

Comment: What is the goal of this? As this looks to me as if it could be solved via a simple change in how the command line parameters are read (providing the path separate from the arguments for example)

Comment: The idea is one whole string entered by a (human) user, there is no separate exe and argument fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the character index after the extension and remove the rest of the string.
like this:

```
string myString = "C:/Test has spaces/More Spaces.exe argument";
int index_Of_ext = myString.LastIndexOf("exe")
    //including "exe"
    + 3;

string output = myString.Remove(index_Of_ext,
                                //starting remove
                                myString.Length - index_Of_ext);
                                //the rest of the string
```

in this way in the output string you miss the part after "exe" (including extension)

Comment: I can't assume the exe is the lastIndexOf because of things like this
C:/Test/t.exe   thisexe

Comment: Maybe search for the *first* ".exe" (notice the leading `.`)?

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this, taking System.IO.Path.GetFileName, and diff with System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName, and reforming it again, but it feels very hackish, and I'm hoping for a better solution